# How to redirect after an error in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using Express for routing and MongoDB for my simple Node blog app (I'm new and just learning) and I need to redirect to the home page if somebody enters the incorrect URL, whenever it attempts to redirect the program crashes.

**Terminal Output:**

```
Server started on 3000
Rendered homepage
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'postTitle' of null at line 115
```

**Router Params / Get**

```
//=== DYNAMIC POSTS ROUTE ===//
app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res){
    const requestedPostTitle = req.params.postId;
    Post.findOne({postTitle: requestedPostTitle}, function(err, foundPost){
        if (!err) {
//FAILS HERE IF INCORRECT URL IS ENTERED INTO BROWSER
            const title   = foundPost.postTitle;
            const date    = foundPost.postDate;
            const content = foundPost.postBody;
            /*res.send(foundPost.postDate);*/
            res.render(`post`, {
                  title: title,
                   date: date,
                content: content
            });

        } /*else {
        res.redirect(`/`);
        console.log(`404 ${requestedPostTitle} does not exist`);
        } */
    });
});
```

The program will only crash if I type in an incorrect URL, after that, none of my pages will reload (I'm assuming because of the (err) callback), I have to restart my server manually and everything works again, nodemon doesn't reset it when it fails.

**root view:**

```
<h1>HOME</h1>
<p><%= pageStartContent %></p>
<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
    <div class="post-box">
        <h3><%= post.postTitle %></h3>
        <p class="date"><%= post.postDate %></p>
        <p class="post-body"><%= post.postBody.substring(0,450) + "..." %></p>
         <a href="posts/<%= post.postTitle %>">Read More</a>
    </div>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res){
    const requestedPostTitle = req.params.postId;
    Post.findOne({postTitle: requestedPostTitle}, function(err, foundPost){
        if (!err && foundPost) {
//FAILS HERE IF INCORRECT URL IS ENTERED INTO BROWSER
            const title   = foundPost.postTitle;
            const date    = foundPost.postDate;
            const content = foundPost.postBody;
            /*res.send(foundPost.postDate);*/
            return res.render(`post`, {
                  title: title,
                   date: date,
                content: content
            });

        }  
        return res.redirect(`/`);
    });
});
```

the code didn't work before (maybe) because you are checking if there an error and if not rendering `post` but this does not mean that the post was found, you need to check if `foundPost` is not `null`.

Comment: I forgot I had to handle if it didn't find a post! is "return" required for res.redirect(`/`);?

Comment: no, but to make the code cleaner, you are able to not include it. does the answer meet your requirements?

Comment: The answer does indeed fit the bill. Waiting the 6 minutes to accept answer =)